# nuget command to just check if any or specific package dependencies have updates and install them?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget

I'm trying to automate testing of new package versions in my CI/CD system

This is what I want:

- Check if a specified list of packages the project depends on have new release versions
- If and only if there are new versions of those packages install those new versions then run my build pipeline to build/run tests/etc to see if the new version of the package breaks something

Are there nuget commands that can do this? I want to have logic that first only checks if there are any new versions of the packages and install those new versions.

I could just run `nuget update YourSolution.sln` every time, but it would be nice to check first if there even are any new packages because then I could just end the build pipeline there. Also `nuget update YourSolution.sln` updates all packages but I want to specify list of packages to update.

Comment: Have you looked at this `nuget` command - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-list), with this option - `-AllVersions`? You could potentially get a list of all versions of a particular package and check that against your projects version. Or you can omit the option `-AllVersions` and get the most recent version of the package and compare. This seems entirely possible though.

Comment: hmm maybe im not reading it right but thats not what i want. Using that i would have to script out listing all the packages and checking the versions against what I have currently installed which is not what I want. Im looking for a command similar to `nuget update YourSolution.sln` or even better something like `nuget update YourSolution.sln package1, package2, etc`.  except I only want it to return a list of packages with updates

Comment: It looks like `Update-Package` command already does what you want, it only updates the package if there is a new version? - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages) - "The same command without -reinstall updates a package to a newer version, if applicable." This can be used on a specific package or on the project level.

Comment: man i think thats almost what i want. is there a way to make it return a specific return code if it updates a package? I would want to be able to programmatically determine if the package was updated and if not then i can have my pipeline exit there, also there is some other logic too I have the hinges on wether or not  the package was updated.

Comment: That's a good question, but I don't see any answer in the documentation. Perhaps try a sample project and upgrade a package and see for yourself? I'm sorry I can't give you a quick answer on that one.